# Fullscreen in Cordova Android InAppBrowser

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

In InAppBrowser.java, I use

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

to have the browser full screen and hidden virtual navigation. It works perfectly. Problem is when I press the home button and then load the application back. At this point, I have displayed the virtual navigation. How can I achieve that the navigation is hidden again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

`dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

`dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);`

in `onResume()`

Comment: Or may be `onStart`

Comment: Adding the code to `onResume` solved my problem. Just one note, the first command must be `dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` I had a bug also in it.